# Discord.py async function does not give any output and does not do anything

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

here is the code:

```
print('hmm1') #testing, this one prints
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&')
client.run('my token', bot=False)

async def testFunction():
    print('hmm') #<- this one does not print.
    channel = await client.get_channel(708848617301082164)
    message_id=715307791379595275
    msg = await client.get_message(channel, message_id)
    await msg.edit(content="L")
    await msg.edit(content="W")
    print('edited message!')
testFunction()
# none of the above works. I only get "hmm1" printed in console.
```

I have no clue what is happening as there is quite literally no error or output of any sort in the console. does anyone know the problem?

Comment: `testFunction()` never gets run. `client.run` hangs. I would recommend actually looking at the documentation and how the API works.

Comment: `client.run()` is a blocking call, meaning it stops the execution. Try `await client.start()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not familiar with asynchronous functions, they need to be `await`ed. Examples of coroutines can be seen in `msg.edit(...`, as `edit()` is a coroutine, therefore you need to `await` it like so: `await testFunction()`

Additionally, `client.get_channel()` and `client.get_message()` aren't coroutines, so they don't need to be awaited.

As Eric mentioned, you'll also want to move your `client.run('...` down to the last line in your file, otherwise it'll block the rest of the script. Here's how the code should be structured:

```py
# imports

# commands, events, functions

# last line
client.run('...
```

---

It looks like you're using some old documentation too, as d.py has moved over to rewrite (v1.x), and it looks as though the `client.get_message()` you were using is actually from [v0.16.x](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.Client.get_message).

I'd recommending wanting to read up on [these changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) to familiarise yourself with rewrite. Try to avoid outdated tutorials as well.

As a little headstart, your `await client.get_message(channel, message_id)` should become `await channel.fetch_message(message_id)`.

---

**References:**

- [Rewrite docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
- [`TextChannel.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)

Comment: @A68AGaming What are the other issues?